# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_13_input to have shape (3,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Im trying to predict a manually encoded data with my keras model but it doesnt work:

```
print(np.array([5.1, 3.5, 1.4]).shape)
prediction = model.predict(np.array([5.1, 3.5, 1.4]))
```

Gives me:

```
(3,)
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_13_input to have shape (3,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

How can I solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add the batch dimension (n_batch, feat_dim) ==> (1,3)

```
inp = Input((3))
x = Dense(10)(inp)
model = Model(inp, x)
X = np.array([5.1, 3.5, 1.4])

model.predict(X[None,:])
```